# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’

Tags: r

I was trying to use overlay function and the code is the following:

```
usa <- map('state',boundary = FALSE, lty=2,plot=FALSE,fill=TRUE)
usa_SP <- map2SpatialPolygons(usa, IDs=usa$names, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat"))

comB.dat <- read.csv("agbregion.csv",header=TRUE)
names(comB.dat) <- c("Lon","Lat","harvDB")
names(AGByr)<- c("Lon","Lat","harvDB")
names(AGBdiff) <- c("Lon","Lat","harvDB")

pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(comB.dat$Lon,comB.dat$Lat))
ptsyr <- SpatialPoints(cbind(AGByr$Lon,AGByr$Lat))
ptsdiff <- SpatialPoints(cbind(AGBdiff$Lon,AGBdiff$Lat))

o <- overlay(pts, usa_SP)
```

But I got the following error:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"SpatialPoints", "SpatialPolygons"’

I don't know what's going on. Could anybody explain it for me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

See help of `?raster::overlay`. Notice the first few lines.

```
## S4 method for signature 'Raster,Raster'
overlay(x, y, ..., fun, filename="", recycle=TRUE, forcefun=FALSE)

## S4 method for signature 'Raster,missing'
overlay(x, y, ..., fun, filename="", unstack=TRUE, forcefun=FALSE)
```

This tells you that this method only works on `Raster` objects, such as `RasterLayer`, `RasterStack` and so on.

Consider using `sp::over`, which is declared to

> consistent spatial overlay for points, grids and polygons: at the spatial locations of object x retrieves the indexes or attributes from spatial object y

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I followed by your advise to use over function and the code is: o <- over(pts, usa_SP, returnList = TRUE), but got another error: Error: not all identicalCRS (x, y) are TRUE. What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: @pandaJ have you tried searching the internet for this error?

Comment: LuštrikYeah, I've done some search and got no relative answer. But  I've already solved the problem and thank you once again.